# error " undefined reference to " at compile time

Tags: c, compiler-errors

when I compile this file it keeps giving me

```
Undefined reference to size
Undefined reference to file
```

I compiled it twice in the second time it give me both error, when the first time it give me only the second error.

can I know exactly what is the problem and how I can solve it?

ps: i use `gcc -o ser server.c` to compile

Sorry I had problem with my Net

```c
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<errno.h>
 #include<arpa/inet.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<netinet/in.h>
 #include<sys/types.h>
 #include<sys/socket.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<fcntl.h>

#define Max_len 1049
void error (char * str)
{
perror(str);
exit(0);
}
```

this the complete code

```
int main (int argc, char ** arg)
 {
      //------------------------- define data type
 int listenfd,connfd,clilen,portno,fil_fd;
 char buff[Max_len], *str,f_name[100],car=0xAA;
 struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
 FILE * file_ptr;         //to store the pointer that point to the read file
     //------------------------- socket intinalizing
 if(argc != 2)          //of user forget to insert the port number
   error("missing port number to complet establishment\n");

 portno=atoi(arg[1]);       //convert the port to int and check if it was within the rang
 if((portno<=22000) || (portno>=23000))
   error("your port number not valid .... pleas insert one in reng (22000,22999)\n");

 listenfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);     //creat the listing socket
     bzero((char *)&servaddr ,sizeof(servaddr));
     servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;       //Ipv4
     servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
     servaddr.sin_port=htons(portno);

 bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));//bind the liten socket to specific port
 listen(listenfd,5);
     //-------------------------- server start to wait to handle requests
 for(;;)
 {
 printf("server wait for connections\n");
 bzero((char *)&cliaddr ,sizeof(cliaddr));  //clear the previus client information
 clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);                //client informaton container
 connfd=accept(listenfd,(struct  sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);
 if(connfd<0)
  error("error in accept this connection\n"); 
   //---------------------------------------        //start the secret hand chacking
 snprintf(buff,/*sizeof(buff)*/1,"%c",0x55);
 write(connfd,buff,sizeof(buff));
    //---------------------------------------       //read file name

  car=0xAA;
  read(connfd,buff,size(buff));
  printf("client reply is %c",buff[0]);
 if(car==buff[0])
     {
       printf("wait for file name \n");
      // bzero(buff,sizeof(buff));
   printf("1#%s\n",buff);
       read(connfd,buff,sizeof(buff));
   printf("2#%s\n",buff);
       strncpy(f_name,buff,sizeof(buff)-1);
       printf("file return name is %s\n",buff);
 }
 else
  error("this is not secure client\n");

 //--------------------------------------   if file found send 1 else 0
 fil_fd=open(f_name,O_RDONLY);      //file opent to be read only
 if(fil_fd < 0)
 {
   snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff),"%d",0);
   write(connfd,buff,1);
   file("file is not found\n");     //retminate connection only
    break;
 }
 else
 {
  snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff),"%d",1);
      write(connfd,buff,1);
  printf("file exists.Send 1 to client\nreading and send the deil\n");
 //-----------------------------------reading and sending
 while(read(buff,1048,fil_fd)>0)
          { 
             printf("%s \n\n",buff);
              write(connfd,buff,sizeof(buff)); //sending the file process
           }//end of uploading

  }//end of if_else
   //-------------------------------------------- close file resources " file"
  close(fil_fd);
  close(connfd);
   }//end of for()
     //--------------------------------------------prepair the server connection
  close(listenfd);
 exit(0);

    return 0;
    }//main()
```

Comment: Can we see the relevant piece of code that's causing the error? We're terrible guessers.

Comment: Without seeing any code we can just guess. My guess is that you're missing an `#include`directive or need to link a library.

Comment: Please post the problematic source code.

Comment: my telepathy says: undefined variables :)

Comment: I am really sorry ... :\

Comment: No wonder you got compiler errors, you only wrote half your program.

Comment: I looked for undefined reference error caused by linker the only thing I am doing is open file read ,write ,close

Comment: Try searching through your program for the offending identifiers (your text editor can probably do that for you), the problem here is that you don't seem to have bothered reading your own code.

Comment: what you mean about "offending identifiers" ?

Comment: I mean `file` and `size`, the ones your errors are complaining about. Search for them in your code.

Comment: Ohh  It work with me :]

this first time to see this error ..... thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You just have two simple errors where you're using undefined identifiers. This:

```
read(connfd,buff,size(buff));
```

should be this::

```
read(connfd,buff,sizeof(buff));
```

and this:

```
file("file is not found\n");
```

should be this:

```
error("file is not found\n");
```

When you use undefined identifiers like this, your compiler has no way of knowing they're just errors, since you might have compiled another source file separately that defines them, so it just assumes you have functions called `size()` and `file()` defined somewhere, and goes to look for them. When it can't find them, it gives you the "undefined reference" error.